# Strict local Martingale arising from Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times, local-martingales

I got an example for a strict local martingale that I do not fully understand.

For the the one dimensional Brownian Motion $B_t$ and a stopping time $\tau=inf\{t \geq 0 |B_t=-1\}$ we know via Doob's optional sampling theorem that $B^{\tau}$ is a martingale.
Now let

$M_t:=\begin{cases}
                    1+B_{t/(1-t)}^{\tau} &\text{  for t} \in [0,1) \\
0 &\text{  for t} \in [1,\infty),
\end{cases}
$

with resprect to the generated filtration:

$ \mathcal{F}^`_t:= \begin{cases}
                    \mathcal{F}_{t/(1-t)} &\text{  for t} \in [0,1) \\
\mathcal{F_{\infty}} &\text{  for t} \in [1,\infty),
\end{cases}$

where $\mathcal{F_{\infty}}:=\sigma(\cup_{t\in\mathbb{R}^+} \mathcal{F}_t)$. Why is $M_t$ a strict local martingale? I guess the problem lies at $t=1$ and the fact that BM is not closable. But then i do not get the difference between $B_{t/(1-t)}^{\tau}$ at $t=1$ and $B_t^{\tau}$ (which is a martingale) at $t=\infty$.

I appreciate your time and thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2077827/36150

Comment: I am very sorry for that, and at the same time very thankful for your hint!