# $(M_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a local martingale, is $(M_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ a martingale for all $T$?

Tags: probability, martingales

- Let $(M_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ a local martingale.

1) Do we have that $(M_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ is a martingale for all $T>0$ ?

2) Do we have that for all sequence of stopping time $(\tau_n)$ s.t. $\tau_n\nearrow \infty $, that $(M_{\tau_n\wedge t})_{t\geq 0}$ is a Martingale ? Or just that there exist such a sequence $(\tau_n)$ ? (the problem it's I can't find any counter example).

- Is it possible that a process $(M_{t})_{t\in[0,T]}$ is a local martingale or such a process is either a martingale either not a martingale ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W$ be a Wiener process and and $\tau = \inf\{ t : W_t = −1 \}$. Define

$$
 X_t = \begin{cases}
  W_{\min(t/(1-t),\tau)} &\text{for } 0 \le t < 1,\\
  -1 &\text{for } 1 \le t < \infty.
 \end{cases}$$

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077827/how-to-show-the-following-process-is-a-local-martingale-but-not-a-martingale), there is answered that this process is a local martingale with respect to the filtration
$$\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_t := \begin{cases} \sigma(W_u; u \leq t/(1-t)) & t \in [0,1) \\ \sigma(W_u; u \geq 0), & t \geq 1. \end{cases}$$
and localizing sequence
$$S_n = (\frac{n}{n+1})I(\tau \geq n) + (\frac{\tau}{\tau+1}+n)I(\tau<n)$$

1) For $T>1$ we have that $(X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ is a local martingale, but we have that
$$\Bbb E [X_t] = \begin{cases} 0 &: t< 1\\ -1 &: t\in [1,T] \end{cases}$$
Therefore $(X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ can't be a martingale.

2) Setting $\tau_n := n$, $n\in \Bbb N$, is a sequence of stopping times with $\tau_n \nearrow \infty$, but $(X_{\tau_n \wedge t})_{t\geq 0}$ is not a martingale, because

$$\Bbb E [X_{\tau_n \wedge t}] = \Bbb E [X_{n \wedge t}] = \begin{cases} 0 &: t< 1\\ -1 &: t \geq 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check your answer more into detail tomorrow, and then, I'll accept it if I'm satisfy :)